# Fingerprint sensor doesn't work on Lenovo yoga 370

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

The fingerprint sensor on my lenovo thinkpad yoga 370 isn't recognised. Can anyone help?

No other errors or anything.

[image: That is what my fingerprint gui shows]

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide more information that may help in trying to resolve this issue for you? Any errors messages, logs or anything that could help.

Comment: I suspect that the internal fingerprint reader isn't attached to USB but some different bus (PCI, I2C, …) whereas the application shown in the image appears to only search for fingerprint readers via USB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the sensor is unsupported on Linux. I would read the [following thread](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Linux-Discussion/Validity-Fingerprint-Reader-Linux/td-p/3352145), and contact Lenovo to express your interest.

Comment: Please don't forget to mark my answer is correct if you're satisfied.